# Google Play shows internal test What's New in production

Tags: android, google-play, apk, google-play-console

I have an app, published in Google Play, that has the Production track and also an Internal Test track. Few days ago, I released a new apk to the Internal Test track, with its own "What's New" comments, different from the ones in the Production Track apk. However, some users have reported that they can see the Internal Test "What's New" comments but they are not internal testers. They see all the information related to the Production Track app (last release date, version, etc.) but the wrong "What's New".

Yesterday, I saved a draft of a new Internal Test apk, with another different "What's New" and today I have verified that it is also visible to some non internal test users, as if it was the Production "What's New".

I am not sure if I am doing something wrong. I have verified in Google Play Console that Production Track has its own What's New, and Internal Test has a different one, but all users seem to see only the Internal Test "What's New".

I sent a couple emails to Google Developer Support asking more info about this, but I haven't got any answer yet. I wanted to know if anybody else had the same issue, or have any ideas of what could I look to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

The internal test track makes your app available for internal testing within minutes.
if you upload the App on Internal Test track than it will only visible to use where you add their email ids from create list page.

Still if you getting issue then you can go through ["https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/7218994?hl=en"](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/7218994?hl=en) link where google play console support team will help you with real time chat and also through email.

Comment: "Chat support is currently not available." - Doesn't matter when you read this

Comment: No you have to wait some time screen will refreshed in certain minutes or seconds  this also happened to me but i got their chat support after waiting some minutes on this page.

Answer (score 0):

We have been publishing updates every three weeks over the past six months. Most google play console responses/reviews to apk published in internal/closed test track has been a minimum of four hours. The google play console chat shows that they are available from 12 am to 12 am but the chat button remains disabled nine out of ten times. The response from the team (possibly L1 support and hence non technical) are template driven. Questions asked of them/over email to customer support do not address your question directly and will require "figuring out".